# Covariant Collection not working

Tags: c#, collections, covariance

Sorry if the question is redundant, but I couldn't find a solution for my particular case.
Please consider this block of code:

```
public interface IPoint {}
public class GazePoint : IPoint {}
public Point AvgPoint(IEnumerable<IPoint> locations) {}

List<GazePoint> gazePoints = new List<GazePoint>();
//...
// this doesn't work:
Point avg = AvgPoint(gazePoints);
```

Could you please explain why it doesn't work (I was assuming C# 4.0 has solved this issue) and how can I change the signature of AvgPoint() method to make it possible to receive different implementations of IPoint. (I don't want to cast gazePoints collection to another type of collection, because it is in a big loop, and I'm concern about the performance.

[Update]: I had defined GazePoint as struct, and that was the source of problem. Still, I don't know why struct is not working here.

Comment: Your `AvgPoint` method does not have a return statement. Please post sample code that demonstrates the actual problem...

Comment: Can you define `doesn't work`? Exception or error?

Comment: Your method signature works fine for me. How are you implementing the rest of it?

Comment: Thanks to all, please find my explanation under @Rufus's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the exact problem is you're having, but here's how it worked for me:

First, some actual class implementations:

```
public interface IPoint
{
    int X { get; set; }
    int Y { get; set; }
}

public class Point : IPoint
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Point()
    {
    }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

public class GazePoint : IPoint
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public GazePoint()
    {
    }

    public GazePoint(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

Then an actual AvgPoint method implementation:

```
public static Point AvgPoint(IEnumerable<IPoint> locations)
{
    if (locations == null || !locations.Any()) return new Point(0, 0);

    return new Point((int) locations.Average(l => l.X), 
        (int) locations.Average(l => l.Y));
}
```

And finally a few tests:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var points = new List<Point>
    {
        new Point(1, 2),
        new Point(3, 4)
    };

    var gazePoints = new List<GazePoint>
    {
        new GazePoint(1, 2),
        new GazePoint(3, 4)
    };

    Point avgPoint = AvgPoint(points);
    Point avgGazePoint = AvgPoint(gazePoints);

    Console.WriteLine("Average Point = {0}, {1}", avgPoint.X, avgPoint.Y);
    Console.WriteLine("Average GazePoint = {0}, {1}", avgGazePoint.X, avgGazePoint.Y);
}
```

If your goal is to have the method return the average in the same type that was passed in, you can make it generic like so:

```
public static T AvgPoint<T>(IEnumerable<T> locations) where T : IPoint, new()
{
    if (locations == null || !locations.Any()) return new T {X = 0, Y = 0};

    return new T {X = (int) locations.Average(l => l.X), 
        Y = (int) locations.Average(l => l.Y)};
}
```

Comment: Rufus, thank you so much for the explanation and writing the whole code for me! Wow! :-)
Please read my answer below!

Comment: Rufus, thank you so much for the explanation and writing the whole code for me! Wow! :-)
My implementation was exactly as yours, with one difference: I had defined _GazePoint_ as **struct**, not a **class**, and it was the source of the problem. Now my code works, but still I don't know why! If I have _GazePoint_ as struct and define an object like 'GazePoint gPoint', then 'gPoint is IPoint' is true, and 'IPoint iPoint = gPoint as IPoint;' works without a problem, but still 'List<GazePoint>' cannot be converted to 'IEnumerable<IPoint>'.
Thank you again!